# Question about integral of non-negative function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am reading Rudin's book Real and Complex Analysis, and I have a question about:

If $f$ is non-negative measurable function, $E$ is a measurable set and $c$ is a constant $0 \leq c < \infty$, then  $\int_E cfd\mu  =c \int_E f d\mu $.

Is there a reason why $c$ cannot be equal to $\infty$?

Comment: So what's $\infty\cdot f?$

Comment: The right-hand side you have  two "numbers" multiplying each other, but the left-hand side is a bit tricky.

Comment: The identity holds and is not hard to show. Simply distinguish the two cased $\int f =0$ (what does this tell you?) and $\int f >0$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Exercise 13 of Chapter 1 asks you to show that $c$ can be $\infty$ in this proposition (labelled 1.24(c) in the third edition).

To see why, let $F = \{ x \in E : f(x) = 0 \}$. If $\mu(E - F) = 0$, then we get
$$
\int_E cf\, d\mu = \int_F cf\, d\mu + \int_{E-F} cf\, d\mu = \mu(F) \cdot 0 + \mu(E - F) \cdot \infty = 0,
$$
and
$$
c\int_E f\, d\mu = c \int_F 0\, d\mu + c \int_{E-F} f\, d\mu = c \cdot 0 + c \cdot 0 = 0.
$$
If $\mu(E-F) > 0$, then we get
$$
\int_E cf\, d\mu = \int_F cf\, d\mu + \int_{E-F} cf\, d\mu = \mu(F) \cdot 0 + \mu(E - F) \cdot \infty = \infty,
$$
and
$$
c\int_E f\, d\mu = c \int_F 0\, d\mu + c \int_{E-F} f\, d\mu = c \cdot 0 + c \cdot k = \infty,
$$
where
$$
k = \int_{E-F} f\, d\mu > 0.
$$
So, $$\int_E cf\, d\mu = c \int_E f\, d\mu$$ for $c = \infty$ as well.